# WindowManager.LayoutParams Animations

Tags: android, animation, imageview, layoutparams

I have an `ImageView` that I'm adding through `WindowManager.addView(ImageView, WindowManager.LayoutParams)`. I want to animate the `ImageView` when it appears on the screen but it doesn't seem to animate when I call `ImageView.startAnimation(Animation)` after the `addView()` method. Here's my code below...

```
image = new ImageView(context);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
image.setAlpha(180);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
windowManager.addView(image, params);
image.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.grow));
```

This is the grow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromXScale="0" 
           android:toXScale="1"
           android:fromYScale="0"
           android:toYScale="1"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:duration="350"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="350" />
</set>
```

The image simply just appears in the window and doesn't animate, does anyone know how I can get the image to animate?

Comment: what is the content of your grow.xml file?

Comment: I just added the contents of the grow.xml file.

Comment: not sure... maybe try longer duration? it takes some time to inflate your layout and animation is not visible.

Comment: I've tried this animation with a normal view on the layout and it looks just fine. I don't think its the duration. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a WindowManager instead of an ordinary View to add the ImageView on.

Comment: maybe try to create the view using LayoutInflater and start the animation in onFinishInflate()

Comment: Check this page out - maybe it is helping:
[http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/dialog-animation-using-windowanimations.html](http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/dialog-animation-using-windowanimations.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use the `windowAnimations` field, the constant you specify must be a system resource; it can not be an application resource because the window manager does not have access to applications. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#windowAnimations)).